# MVC1 project templates in VS 2010 beta?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

Does anyone know if I can put the MVC 1 project templates in VS 2010 beta?  If so, link? I have found a few links on the internets but they all link to a Codeplex project that doesn't have this particular project anymore.

Comment: Have you tried?  They might take a little altering, but if you open them in an xml editor it might become obvious what you need to do (e.g., 9.0 => 10.0)

Comment: Phil Haack has written a blog about this: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/05/18/aspnetmvc-vs2010-beta1.aspx

Comment: Thanks, For whatever reason I didn't read the whole thing and jumped off the page, after rereading Phils post it's right there in front of my face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misread Phil Haacks' blog post, it's RIGHT THERE IN FRONT OF ME. (Thanks Pbirkoff):

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/05/18/aspnetmvc-vs2010-beta1.aspx